# Plotting with NMaximize

Tags: plotting, numerics

I have the following:

```
F = CDF[NormalDistribution[]];
p[m_, s_, t_] = F[(t - m)/s] - F[(-t - m)/s];
nmax[m_, s_, my_] := NMaximize[{p[m, s, t]/p[my, 1, t], t > 0}, {t}]
nmax[.3, .8, .2][[1]]
```

[image]

```
my = .5;
RegionPlot[{nmax[m, s, my][[1]] < 1}, {s, 0, 1}, {m, -Sqrt[1 + my^2], 
  Sqrt[1 + my^2]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, All}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
Clear[my]
```

[image]

It appears that `RegionPlot` does not substitute the current values of `s` and `m` before trying `nmax`, and then it outputs an empty plot.

How to fix this?

Comment: Can you cut and paste the code you are using rather than a screenshot?  It will make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert : Thank you for your comment. I have now done this.

Comment: If I add `?NumericQ` to the arguments of `nmax` (a common trick in cases like this), I get an error message of `Throw::nocatch: Uncaught Throw[$Failed,Optimization\`Utilities\`OptimizationException[]] returned to top level.`  That ain't right.  (MM 12.1 under Mac OS.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert : Thank you for your second comment as well. Sorry, I am not proficient with Mathematica. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: No, I don't;  it smells like a bug in Mathematica to me, to be honest.  I mainly added the comment so that the real experts are aware of the problem.

Comment: Thank you Michael for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)

F = CDF[NormalDistribution[]];
p[m_, s_, t_] = F[(t - m)/s] - F[(-t - m)/s];
nmax[m_?NumericQ, s_?NumericQ, my_?NumericQ] := 
 NMaximize[{p[m, s, t]/p[my, 1, t], t > 0}, {t}]
nmax[.3, .8, .2][[1]]

(* 1.18867 *)

my = 1/2;
```

There is no region within the plot where `nmax[m, s, my][[1]] < 1`

```
Plot3D[nmax[m, s, my][[1]],
 {s, 0, 1}, {m, -Sqrt[1 + my^2], Sqrt[1 + my^2]},
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, 5/4},
 ClippingStyle -> None]
```

[image]

```
nmax[1, 1, my][[1]]

(* 1. *)
```

The region in the closed interval {1, 5/4} is

```
RegionPlot[
 1 <= nmax[m, s, my][[1]] <= 5/4, {s, 0, 1}, {m, -Sqrt[1 + my^2], 
  Sqrt[1 + my^2]},
 AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! First I have tried this without `Clear["Global`*"]` and then  `RegionPlot` still would not substitute the current values of `s` and `m` before trying `nmax`. But your code worked with `Clear["Global`*"]``. Can you explain why? I am sorry, I don't know what `"Global`*"' is. Where can I read more about this?

Comment: `Clear["Global\`*"]` clears all definitions in the `Global` context to insure that any prior definitions don't shadow the intended definitions.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. It is still unclear to me, though, how such shadowing may occur. Doesn't any new definition (say of `nmax`) completely supersede the previous definitions of the same command? Sorry for further bothering you -- I just would like to get more of a lesson here.

Comment: I don't have any ready examples; however, I generally start any stand-alone problem with `Clear["Global\`*"]`